# Python Server Socket: check if it exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, serversocket

A microcontroller program opens a server socket waiting for connections. Then enters a 'forever' loop listening for connections and treating them.
What if the server socket gets lost somehow? I look for a method to check if the server socket is available and if not: restart it.

If this is not the normal way to treat sockets please let me know a better way. Sorry for the abstract form - I actually found no suitable code.

```
while( True ):                         # until Reset or power down
    if( not server_socket_active() ):  # (1) looking for such a function
        open_server_socket()
        start_listening()
    if( client_connect ):
        handle_client_data()
```

I have a working connection with Server Sockets and Client Sockets connecting to it. 
It uses a polling loop with

```
socket.socket()
```

So no code is needed except for a sequence/method/function performing (1).
Thank you for any advice. Or coud it be done with socket.socket() ?

Comment: Why do you think the server socket could just got lost somehow? This is a local socket, fully controlled by your program. This is like thinking that the content of some variable in your code could just magically change without having you done anything in your program. The socket gets only lost if you explicitly close it in your program (and it gets closed implicitly on program exit).

Comment: Thanks Steffen for your comment. Unfortunately stand-alone systems which should work forever sometimes loose part of their running modules, in this case the server socket and dependent core modules. I trace my python program and serve ('feed') a watchdog if something fails. So I was looking for a method to check if the s-socket is still alive to include it in my watchdog loop.

Comment: While writing this I was thinking about trying to connect a client socket (on the same host with the server socket) to the server and wait for success. If not, something with the server could be wrong. I will try and answer my question it it works.

Comment: *"...sometimes loose part of their running modules, in this case the server socket and dependent core modules..."* - huh? Are you saying that if you have a running program then parts of the *running* program can suddenly vanish (i.e. without being explicitly freed by code designed to do this) while the rest is still running? If this would be the case then computing would be much more unreliable than it actually is. It would be different if you mean that some process crashes, but then it is the whole process and not some part of it.

Comment: If only one bit is changed (which is in a word of active code or data) you get problems. Dig a bit into hardware and you will find loosing bits is a severe problem. The stochastic rates are low, but large amounts of data multiplied with long up-times make it very probable. Good computers use ecc memory, microcontrollers use static RAM to keep rates low. We had even some microcontrollers 'forgetting' FLASH data after a few years of operation. Temperature, radioactivity and voltage peaks (transients) are a common cause.

Comment: With an actual PC a typical magnitude is a week. Modern code usually is not very efficient and only a few percent are used by an application. This is why you recognize it very rarely. It is almost no problem with typical desktop environments. Controllers which should work for ten or twenty years with small and highly dense code (like heating controllers) should be able to recognize such problems and react accordingly (e.g. reboot). Actually I am working on such a system.

Comment: I doubt that a bit flip in hardware will just cause a listen socket to close but let everything else function as before. While in theory possible I think it is absolutely unlikely that this is your main concern when having unstable hardware. Likely your application will have crashed thousands of times because of this flaky hardware before such situation will happen.